# API in URL doesn't work but it does in Terminal

Tags: api, terminal

I have the following API:
curl "https://api.prospect.silktide.com/api/v1/report/145b2bec22e731280103639ef580e5f4eb809942" --header "api-key: f92022fc208a3b83fe2aa85d239560f7f0a55823"

It works perfectly fine in terminal, however when I put it on my web browser as:

https://api.prospect.silktide.com/api/v1/report/145b2bec22e731280103639ef580e5f4eb809942" --header "api-key: f92022fc208a3b83fe2aa85d239560f7f0a55823"

It doesn't give any data the same way as terminal, any idea why?

Comment: You cannot add a header in a browser just like that

Comment: This is a dummy API key, I hope?